# django-tabbed-admin Django 2.0 compatibility issue with RequestContext

Tags: python, django

Today i was trying tabbed admin with Django 2.0.7 and i got this error:

> Exception Type: | TypeError
> context must be a dict rather than RequestContext.
>
> Exception Location:
> djangostack-2.0.7-0/apps/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.7-py3.6.egg/django/template/context.py in make_context, line 274

It seems the whole issue starts from here
/tabbed_admin/templatetags/tabbed_admin_tags.py in render_tab_fieldsets_inlines:
at line 40 shown below:

```
39 context["fieldset"] = f
40 return render_to_string(template, context)
41 elif entry['type'] == 'inline':
```

how to fix this?

i tried

```
return render_to_string(template, {'context':context})
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: There is a lot of code missing for us to help you out, however I think that there is an update for tabbed-admin and this error may be fixed, since this https://github.com/omji/django-tabbed-admin/blob/master/tabbed_admin/templatetags/tabbed_admin_tags.py is different than your code.

Comment: Thanks so much, your link lead me to the solution